# how to add pcf to shadow maps

Tags: maps, shadow, hlsl, directx-9

I found this link which explains a little about pcf shadow mapping. I looked through the code sample provided and I cannot work out what the offset array is. I'm assuming it is an array of float2 and I know that it will offset the pixel to give the neighbouring ones. I just can't figure out what the offset should be set too.

Link: http://www.gamerendering.com/2008/11/15/percentage-closer-filtering-for-shadow-mapping/

Here is the code

```
float result;
result = shadow2DProj(shadowMap,texCoord+offset[0]);
result += shadow2DProj(shadowMap,texCoord+offset[1]);
result += shadow2DProj(shadowMap,texCoord+offset[2]);
result += shadow2DProj(shadowMap,texCoord+offset[3]);
result /= 4.0; // now result will hold the average shading
```

I must just be missing something simple

Any help is appreciated

Thank you,

Mark

Comment: What happens if you remove the offset values?

Comment: You must set the texture compare mode of the shadow map to `GL_COMPARE_REF_TO_TEXTURE`. That will give you hardware PCF. This is actually explained in the article you linked...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I notice you are using shadow2DProj, as far as I am aware this is a GLSL function and the equivalent in HLSL/CGSL is tex2Dproj. If you are getting a blank screen then this may lead you closer as you should be able to temporarily remove the offset values.

Good luck mate I am new at this too so I know how this is :)

Comment: The code i posted there is not mine that is sample code i found online. I managed to workout the offset it should be 1/width of texture. I now understand how pcf works a lot bette. Essentially what you do is workout how many pixels are in shadow in an area around the current pixel you are on in the pixel shader. You then divide that number by the amount of pixels you tested and set the shadow attenuation to that value. I am also using HLSL.